# Measurability of the set of maximal elements of a poset

Tags: general-topology, measure-theory, order-theory

Let $(E, <)$ be a poset. We can endow $E$ with the order topology, and thus view it as a measurable space $(E,\mathcal{E})$ with the Borel $\sigma$-algebra.

Is the set $M$ of maximal elements of $E$, $M:= \{x : y \leq x \text{ for all } y \}$ measurable with respect to $(E,\mathcal{E})$?

It is quite straightforward to write $M = \bigcap_{y \in E} (-\infty,y)^c$, where $(-\infty,y) := \{ x \in E: x < y\}$. Hence, one sufficient condition is that $E$ is countable. However, I am wondering if there are any more necessary or sufficient conditions we can impose.

Countability is not necessary. For example, $M$ is measurable for $[0,\infty]$  with the usual order, since $M = \{\infty\} = \bigcap_{n \in \mathbb{N}} [0,n]^c$. More generally, $M$ will be countable if we can determine whether an element is maximal by only 'comparing' it against countably many other elements, but I am not sure if this is a notion that has been formalised.

Comment: You need to explain what is order topology on a poset. For total orders it's clear, but not for arbitrary posets.

Comment: @Jakobian The standard topology constructed via rays is to be assumed

Comment: @FShrike there are multiple ways to give poset a topology and it's not standard to assume one over the other. That's why I'm asking *the author* for an explanation

Comment: @Jakobian Apologies, admittedly I do not know too much about topoolgies on posets, and misread the Wikipedia page for the order topology and assumed it was about posets in general. I suppose the question can be asked for Alexandrov topolgy (which is generated by upper sets), but more generally is there some topology induced by the partial order for which the set of maximal elements is measurable?

Comment: Though I suppose the set of maximal elements is open in the Alexandrov topology, and hence measurable in the Borel $\sigma$-algebra...